# Converting float/double to IEEE hex representation

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to see the hexadecimal representation of a float value in WinDbg. It is easily possible to convert a hex value to float using `.formats`:

```
0:000> .formats 0x41133333
  [...]
  Float:   low 9.2 high 0
  Double:  5.3941e-315
```

But how about the other way round?

I have tried

```
0:000> ? 9.2
Syntax error at '9.2'
0:000> ?? 9.2
double 9.1999999999999993
0:000> ? @@(9.2)
Evaluate expression: 9 = 00000000`00000009
0:000> ? @@(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int64>(9.2))
Evaluate expression: 9 = 00000000`00000009
```

So far, the only way I could convert a float was through an indirection over memory:

```
0:000> ef 00000001`00003acc 9.2
0:000> dd 00000001`00003acc L1
00000001`00003acc  41133333
```

However, I'd not like to change the contents of the memory during debugging. To conflicts with the program's memory, I could use `.dvalloc`, but it just makes the nesessary steps more complex.

Is there an easier built-in way for converting floats/double to hex?

Comment: You could use `calc` :). Seriously, if you haven't found it, it probably doesn't exists but to be sure, I'd send a mail to defragtools@microsoft.com. Most likely, Andrew Richards will pick it up and you'll get a definitive answer.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: that's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I had a crude code that did this i cleaned it up a bit and uploaded the src and a compiled dll take a look it will do what you want

https://github.com/blabberer/FloatToHex

the src is simple engextcpp

```
#include <engextcpp.hpp>
union FloatToChar {
    float           flt;
    unsigned char   fltc[4];
};
class EXT_CLASS : public ExtExtension {
public:
    EXT_COMMAND_METHOD(f2h);
};
EXT_DECLARE_GLOBALS();
EXT_COMMAND(
    f2h,
    "Converts Float to HexString",
    "{{opt:+:}}{;s;<float>;example usage !f2h 9.2 will return 41133333}"
    )
{
    PCSTR arg = GetUnnamedArgStr(0);
    char *endptr;
    double in = strtod(arg,&endptr);
    FloatToChar inflt;
    inflt.flt = (float)in;
    Out(
        "%-30s%02X%02X%02X%02X\n",
        "32_Bit_Float",
        inflt.fltc[3],
        inflt.fltc[2],
        inflt.fltc[1],
        inflt.fltc[0]
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Loading an extension just for this purpose still looks a bit too much for the task, but if you have already written this code to achieve the task, there may not be an easier solution. Is it possible that I can't use negative floats with your code? I switched to {{custom}} and GetRawArgs() to bypass that limitation. (I confess: the DLL on Github did not work for me, so I compiled it on my own, making it a Visual Studio solution first.)

Comment: i dont prefer parsing myself so was wondering why negative inputs dont work when i am taking an input as  string it turns out that default options for named arguments start with / or -  so  the framework was interpreting -9.2 as a named argument instead of a string unnamed argument and failing disable it with a directive {{opt:+}} now inputting negative arguments work with framework parsing github src changed